# Render directive conditionally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I've been struggling all day to find a way to conditionally render a directive on an element.
I ended up on this page: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html but then I wasn't able to append my compiled template (using vue-template-compiler, since I'm using some version of vue which doesn't include the compiler).

At the end of the day this is what I figured:

```html
<div>Some foo</div>
<template v-if="withDirective">
  <input :value="value"
         :disabled="disabled"
         :type="type"
          v-some-directive="someValue" />
</template>
<template v-else>
  <input :value="value"
         :disabled="disabled" 
         :type="type" />
</template>
<div>Some bar</div>
```

Is there a better way?
I have a lot more attributes on the input, so there's really a lot of duplicate code which I would love to avoid.
This html is inside a custom component, so all the values like disabled, required, etc, are props passed from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found so far is compiling a string template conditionally using `compileToFunctions`.
So instead of having the `template` tags and the v-if in the template, I simply add the conditional directive(s) before compiling the component.

**ATTENTION**

> Keep in mind that the compilation is runtime, I don't have enough experience with Vue (yet) to tell if this way is faster than using v-if. What is sure is that we saved a lot of duplicate lines in the template, which is handy when editing common parts.